# Is there a way to pass an extra argument through or with .filter()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the simplified example below the creatures array is filtered for all `objects` with the species Zombie.  As it stands the callback function `filterCreatures` can only search for the word Zombie.  However I'd like to pass in a variable with different creature names so that I can reuse that function to search for every type of monster. For example it would look something like, `return a.species === creatureType;`  How do I do this?  Is there a way to pass an extra variable with `.filter()`?  Thanks so much!

```js
'use strict';
 
var creatures = [], zombieCreatures = [];
 
var filterCreatures;
 
creatures = [
  {species: 'Zombie', hitPoints: 90},
  {species: 'Orc', hitPoints: 40},
  {species: 'Skeleton', hitPoints: 15},
  {species: 'Zombie', hitPoints: 85}
];
 
filterCreatures = function(a) {
  return a.species === 'Zombie';
}
 
zombieCreatures = creatures.filter(filterCreatures);

console.log(zombieCreatures);
```

Comment: If you wrap your filter into a function that accepts a second argument, I think that would accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create something like this. Create a function which takes the `filter` property and returns your actual filter function.

```js
'use strict';
 
var creatures = [], zombieCreatures = [];
 
var filterFactory;
 
creatures = [
  {species: 'Zombie', hitPoints: 90},
  {species: 'Orc', hitPoints: 40},
  {species: 'Skeleton', hitPoints: 15},
  {species: 'Zombie', hitPoints: 85}
];
 
filterFactory = function(filter) {
  return function(a) {
     return a.species === filter;
  };
};
 
zombieCreatures = creatures.filter(filterFactory('Zombie'));

console.log(zombieCreatures);

zombieCreatures = creatures.filter(filterFactory('Orc'));

console.log(zombieCreatures);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind` function like this

```
filterCreatures = function(creatureType, a) {
  return a.species === creatureType;
}

zombieCreatures = creatures.filter(filterCreatures.bind(null, 'Zombie'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by slightly modifying the code.

Create a function which will accept any array and a to be filtered element

```js
var creatures = [],
  zombieCreatures = [];

var filterCreatures;

creatures = [{
    species: 'Zombie',
    hitPoints: 90
  },
  {
    species: 'Orc',
    hitPoints: 40
  },
  {
    species: 'Skeleton',
    hitPoints: 15
  },
  {
    species: 'Zombie',
    hitPoints: 85
  }
];

function filterCreatures(array, crt) {
  return array.filter(function(a) {
    return a.species === crt;
  })
}


console.log(filterCreatures(creatures, 'Skeleton'));
```